# How to rotate a circle in android canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I drawn a circle like this
`canvas.drawCircle(40, 40, 50, mPaint);`
I want to rotate this circle, how can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by rotating the circle? Doesn't a circle look the same at any rotation angle?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö rotation from another point not its center

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rotating the circle, you should rotate the canvas by method of Canvas.rotate() . You could look docs for this method.